# Excel filter table data to meet the sampling requirement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sampling

I need to obtain 2 random cases for each complaint handler in a data table that can be used for sampling.

[image: Data table in excel containing all data]

Assuming I would have to group the data using the Handler ID (unique reference for each complaint handler) and then some how select two random pieces of information from the groups.

[image: Pivot of table using Handler ID]

I have grouped this information using a Pivot. All case handlers in this has 2 or less cases so no further action needs to be taken on these. However, there is an exception with Chris Smith (h238) as he has three cases and the max sampling is 2 per case handler.

I need a script that will select two random cases for Chris and remove any additional cases (so we have a random sample of 2 cases).

I can do this manually by going filtering table by Chris' cases and then removing cases until there is only two remaining. However, the actual data set would be much larger so would be very time consuming and this process needs to be ran several times a day with the data in the table continually changing.

Comment: Does it depend on "Outcome" data?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting one!

Here is my solution. I've tried several possible versions.
Try 1:
As per originally posted data - Chris Smith (h238) is overloaded with 1 task and there are enough people to reassign tasks: 
[image: try1]
Try 2:
Chris Smith (h238) is still overloaded, but this time with 3 tasks and there are enough people to reassign tasks:
[image: try2]
Try 3:
Poor Chris Smith (h238) is totally overloaded, but this time there are not enough people to reassign tasks: 
[image: try3]
Try 4:
This time Jane Doe (h324) is in line with Chris Smith (h238) - they are overloaded, but there are not enough people to reassign tasks:
[image: try4]

Cases where there are no overloaded or no free people are breaking with appropriate messages, didn't do screenshot.
The code:

```
Sub ReassignCases()
' Variables
' people  related:
Dim handlerIdRange As Range, handlerId As Range
Dim maxCases As Long
Dim cases As Long
Dim name As String, id As String
Dim nameTo As String, idTo As String
Dim caseRef As Range

' arrays:
Dim overloaded() As String
Dim free() As String

' counters:
Dim o As Long, f As Long, i As Long, c As Long, j As Long

' unique values container
Dim handlersList As New Collection

' output
Dim msg As String

Dim workSht As Worksheet

'----------------------------------------------------
' reassign the sheet name as you have in your workbook
Set workSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' parameter that can be changed if needed
maxCases = 2

With workSht
    Set handlerIdRange = Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

' get the list of handlers
On Error Resume Next
For Each handlerId In handlerIdRange
    handlersList.Add handlerId & ";" & handlerId.Offset(0, -1), handlerId & ";" & handlerId.Offset(0, -1)
Next
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

For i = 1 To handlersList.Count

    ' look for overloaded
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(handlerIdRange, Split(handlersList(i), ";")(0)) > maxCases Then
        ReDim Preserve overloaded(o)
        ' adding to array: id;name;qty of cases
        overloaded(o) = handlersList.Item(i) & ";" & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(handlerIdRange, Split(handlersList(i), ";")(0))
        o = o + 1
    ' look for those who has less the 2 cases. If one has 2 cases - he is not free
    ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(handlerIdRange, Split(handlersList(i), ";")(0)) < maxCases Then
        ReDim Preserve free(f)
        free(f) = handlersList.Item(i)
        f = f + 1
    End If
Next

' check whether there are overloaded handlers
If Not Not overloaded Then
    ' if yes - proceed further
    Else
    ' if not - inform and quit
    MsgBox "There are no overloaded handlers.", vbInformation, "Info"
    Exit Sub
End If

' check whether there are free handlers
If Not Not free Then
    ' if yes - proceed further
    Else
    ' if not - inform and quit
    o = UBound(overloaded) + 1
    MsgBox "There " & IIf(o = 1, "is ", "are ") & o & " overloaded " & IIf(o = 1, "handler", "handlers") & ", but 0 free.", vbInformation, "Info"
    Exit Sub
End If
msg = ""
' go through array of overloaded
For i = LBound(overloaded) To UBound(overloaded)
    ' Id of overloaded
    id = Split(overloaded(i), ";")(0)
    ' Name of overloaded
    name = Split(overloaded(i), ";")(1)
    ' number of over cases = total assigned - 2 (max cases)
    cases = Split(overloaded(i), ";")(2) - maxCases
    '

    ' check that there some free people left
    If Not c > UBound(free) Then
    ' go through each handler in the array of free people
    ' free people are those, who have only 1 task and can take another 1

    ' if c was not used yet it is 0, otherwise, it will continue looping through free people
        For c = c To UBound(free)

            idTo = Split(free(c), ";")(0)
            nameTo = Split(free(c), ";")(1)

            ' find the first match of the id in Id range
            Set caseRef = handlerIdRange.Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues)
            ' give an outcome of what was reassigned
            msg = msg & "Task: " & caseRef.Offset(0, 1).Text & " was reassigned from " & name & " (" & id & ") "
                With caseRef
                    .Value = idTo
                    .Offset(0, -1).Value = nameTo
                End With
            msg = msg & "to " & nameTo & " (" & idTo & ")" & Chr(10)
            cases = cases - 1
            ' when all needed cases are passed to other stop looking through free people
            If cases = 0 Then Exit For
        Next
        ' if the loop through free people is finished,
        ' but there left some more - go to warning creation
        If Not cases = 0 Then GoTo leftCases
    Else
leftCases:
        msg = msg & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "There are no more free handlers." & Chr(10)

        For j = i To UBound(overloaded)
            msg = msg & Split(overloaded(j), ";")(1) & " is still overloaded with " & cases & " cases." & Chr(10)
        Next

        msg = msg & Chr(10) & "Operation completed with warnings." & Chr(10)
        msg = msg & Chr(10) & "Would you like to save results?"
        If MsgBox(msg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Done") = vbYes Then SaveResults (msg)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

msg = msg & Chr(10) & "Operation completed." & Chr(10)

msg = msg & Chr(10) & "Would you like to save results?"

If MsgBox(msg, vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Done") = vbYes Then SaveResults (msg)

End Sub

Sub SaveResults(Text As String)

Dim lines() As String, temp() As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim FileName As String

lines = Split(Text, Chr(10))

For i = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
    If lines(i) Like "Task:*" Then
        ReDim Preserve temp(j)
        temp(j) = lines(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next

Dim fi As Long

FileName = "Task reassignment log"

FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=FileName, FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", Title:="Saving as text...")

If UCase(FileName) = "FALSE" Then Exit Sub

If CheckFileExists(FileName) Then
    If MsgBox("The file " & Dir(FileName) & " already exists. Overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        WriteToFile FileName, temp
    Else
        i = 0
        Do Until Not CheckFileExists(FileName)
            For j = Len(FileName) To 1 Step -1
                If Mid(FileName, j, 1) = Application.PathSeparator Then Exit For
            Next

            FileName = Left(FileName, j)
            If i = 0 Then
                FileName = FileName & "Task reassignment log.txt"
            Else
                FileName = FileName & "Task reassignment log (" & i & ")" & ".txt"
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        WriteToFile FileName, temp
        MsgBox "The file was saved with " & Chr(34) & Dir(FileName) & Chr(34) & " name", vbInformation
    End If
Else
    WriteToFile FileName, temp
End If


End Sub

Sub WriteToFile(FileName As String, Text() As String)
Dim i As Long

Open FileName For Output As #1
    For i = LBound(Text) To UBound(Text)
        Write #1, Text(i)
    Next
Close #1
End Sub

Function CheckFileExists(FileName As String) As Boolean
CheckFileExists = False
If Not Dir(FileName) = "" Then CheckFileExists = True
End Function
```

**Note**
1. I didn't randomize a list of free people, so they are taken one by one. If you do need this - you can easily find a macro to randomize an array and insert it as side function.
2. I'm not sure that it works perfectly - comments are appreciated!

**Update**
I've slept on this question and decided to complete my answer with such an essential thing as saving the reassignment log to text file, so the code is updated.